# .htaccess redirect to example.com except for directory redirect to example.com/example

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, https

Variations on this question have been asked, and so I apologize in advance -- I simply cannot get this to work. I know the devil is in the details with the .htaccess, so I'm sure I'm missing something small.

Here's what have:

I have a page: example.com/ which redirects all traffic to its https equivalent. I'm building the next version of the same site inside of the directory example.com/example.com/ I'm trying to write a redirect that will send all traffic to its https equivalent except for the directory that I'm working in, which should be left alone. My problem is, whenever I try to access example.com/example.com/ I get redirected to the 404 of example.com (which makes sense). I just can't get the redirect to not loop indefinitely.

I currently have a redirect from http to https for example.com as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

This works just fine, and only causes troubles when I try to access the subfolder.

**tl;dr
Here's what I need:**

```
http://example.com/ REDIRECTS TO https://example.com/

http://example.com/[anything else] REDIRECTS TO https://example.com/[anything else]

https://example.com/example.com/ SHOULD NOT REDIRECT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer please?

Comment: @Zulu first condition is met if the port is 80 (not https). Second condition is met if the REQUEST_URI is different than example.com